# Resolve ip addresses of a headless service

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I created a service, which has 3 pods assigned.

[image]

I would like to access the service through its hostname by an other service in the same project. How can I do that?

Tried:

```
alxtbk@dns-test:~$ ping elassandra-0.elassandra
ping: elassandra-0.elassandra: Name or service not known

alxtbk@dns-test:~$ ping elassandra-0.default.svc.cluster.local
ping: elassandra-0.default.svc.cluster.local: Name or service not known

alxtbk@dns-test:~$ ping elassandra.default.svc.cluster.local
ping: elassandra.default.svc.cluster.local: Name or service not known
```

What is the correct way to resolve the ip adresses of the headless service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For such Services, a cluster IP is not allocated, kube-proxy does not
> handle these services, and there is no load balancing or proxying done
> by the platform for them. How DNS is automatically configured depends
> on whether the service has selectors defined.
>
> **With selectors**
>
> For headless services that define selectors, the endpoints controller
> creates Endpoints records in the API, and modifies the DNS
> configuration to return A records (addresses) that point directly to
> the Pods backing the Service.
>
> **Without selectors**
>
> For headless services that do not define selectors, the endpoints
> controller does not create Endpoints records. However, the DNS system
> looks for and configures either:
>
> CNAME records for ExternalName-type services.
>
> A records for any Endpoints that share a name with the service, for all other types.

so you maybe be able to do:

```
kubectl get ep
```

to get the endpoints and then use them inside another kubernetes service.

Comment: Yes with kubectl get ep a list of the ip adresses is returned. Will the ip adresses remain the same in a statefulset? I was hoping to use something like "elassandra-0.hostname" in my main application, which would point to one of the pods. What is the best way to configure the network? If I assign a ClusterIp to the service, would its hostname resolve and do the loadbalancing? Especially for cassandra it doesnt matter, which node i connect to

Comment: yes , you then need to expose them on service of type clusterIp  , kube proxy will take care of load balancing , you can do session persistence on service as well

Comment: Thank you. Could you tell me, how its possible to activate/ deactivate session persistence?

Comment: @AlexTbk `sessionAffinity: ClientIP` . in service.yml file

Comment: https://medium.com/@diegomrtnzg/redirect-your-users-to-the-same-pod-by-using-session-affinity-on-kubernetes-baebf6a1733b

Comment: In general, if you write a headless service with a selector, you should be able to access it by the hostname: `elassandra.default.svc.cluster.local`. If you need an example, we use it in Hazelast, you can check our sample service definition here: 

https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/blob/master/hazelcast-integration/kubernetes/samples/springboot-k8s-hello-world/deployment.yaml#L51